# Refer to object properties dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I have an exemplar of the class `ClsFruit` With following member variables:

[image]

I also have an excel sheet with data, like this:

[image]

I don't feel like Populating the object using direct references like

```
Fruit.Name = FruitSheet.Cells(1,2).Value
Fruit.Color = FruitSheet.Cells(2,2).Value
Fruit.Price = FruitSheet.Cells(3,2).Value
```

is the way to go because it's tons of repetitive code and positions of items on the worksheet might change in the future. So I wanted to loop through the first column in excel `Name-Color-Price`and populate the object dynamically something like this:

```
Dim rg As Excel.Range
Set rg = FruitSheet.Range("A1", "A3")
Dim Cell As Variant

For Each Cell In rg
    Fruit(Cell.Value) = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next Cell
```

But this `Fruit(Cell.Value)` construct doesn't work, I get "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Is there a way around it?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on class object but I believe you might want to explore the [`CallByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/calling-a-property-or-method-using-a-string-name) function.

Comment: @JvdV: Not quite the right link but the right function ;-)

Comment: Right, just needed to link to `VBA` documentation :) @Storax

Comment: Excuse me, but I think it's for calling methods only, I don't see how can I implement it for a member variable (as in my case)

Comment: You can also implement it for member variables.

Comment: Through get/let?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Could the data sheet be set up with Name, Color, and Price as the columns and each instance be in the rows?

Comment: Yes they could, I don't see much difference tbh.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov see my proposed solution below using a table and worksheet proxy

Comment: You could use the approach below having the table as you currently do with the instances in columns and the rows being the properties. I just find it easier to think of the tables with the properties as the column headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to do something like that

```
For Each Cell In rg
    Select Case Cell.Value
        Case "Name"
            fruit.Name = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Case "Color"
            fruit.Color = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Case "Price"
            fruit.Price = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End Select
Next Cell
```

Another way would be to have corresponding propertiers in your class. Then you could use [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function)

```
For Each Cell In rg
    CallByName fruit, cell.value, VbLet, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next Cell
```

**Update**: The class has to be changed like that

```
    Option Explicit

    Public mName As String
    Public mColor As String
    Public mPrice As Long

    Property Let name(nValue As String)
        mName = nValue
    End Property
    Property Get name() As String
        name = mName
    End Property

   ' continue with similar properties for the other member variables
```

**Update 2**:As pointed out in the comments it is not neccessary to have Let/Get etc. One can stick to public member variables and CallByName will just work fine. It is just IMHO the cleaner approach on the long run, see [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/#Why_we_use_Properties)

Comment: The `CallByName` is nice. Was working on it myself too. Beaten me to it =)

Comment: No need for `Let` or `Get` for me... would just work. For me when in your `Sub` you `Set`  fruit object like: `Dim Fruit As Object: Set Fruit = New ClsFruit`. No expert on the subject though

Comment: Yes, right, there is indeed no need. One can just work with the public members of the class. It's just "[cleaner](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/#Why_we_use_Properties)" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a worksheet proxy will do what you want, I think. This will return a collection of your objects:

```
WorksheetProxy class
Option Explicit

Private Property Get Table() As ListObject
    Set Table = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
End Property

Private Property Get NameColumnIndex() As Long
    NameColumnIndex= Table.ListColumns("Name").Index
End Property

Private Property Get ColorColumnIndex() As Long
    ColorColumnIndex= Table.ListColumns("Color").Index
End Property

Private Property Get PriceColumnIndex() As Long
    PriceColumnIndex= Table.ListColumns("Price").Index
End Property

Private Property Get Data() As Collection

    Dim result As Collection
    Set result = New Collection

    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    For Each currentRow In Table.ListRows

        Dim currentItem As ClsFruit
        Set currentItem = New ClsFruit

        currentItem.Name= currentRow.Range(ColumnIndex:=NameColumnIndex).value
        currentItem.Color= currentRow.Range(ColumnIndex:=ColorColumnIndex).value
        currentItem.Price= currentRow.Range(ColumnIndex:=PriceColumnIndex).value

        result.Add currentItem

    Next

    Set Data = result

End Property
```

Mathieu Guindon has a discussion of this approach here: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/12/08/there-is-no-worksheet/

In the comments section is a link to his example workbook.